# run time collections in express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating a web app, where user can create questions. Every time user creates a question a collection should be created, where all the answers to that question should be saved as documents in that collection.

Comment: Too broad question, not satisfied for StackOverflow

Comment: I am new to coding and StackOverflow, give me time ill come with better questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use mongodb ORM - `mongoose` for making your data models like that

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var questionSchema = Schema({
  title    : String,
  text     : String,
  user     : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  answers : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]
});

var answerSchema = Schema({
  user : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  text    : String,
});

var Question  = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
var Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', answerSchema);
```

So you will store array of answer ids inside question and can populate data:

```
Question.findOne().populate('answers').exec(function(err, doc){
  console.log(doc.answers) // here populated answers models
})
```

Also you need describe User model and extend with additional data Question and Answer